# Return packets via squid running as tproxy not working

Tags: squid, ipv6, ipv4, transparent-proxy

I have been trying to get this to work properly for two days now and I desperately need assistance. I have configured Squid 3 as a proxy listening on port 3129 with the tproxy flag, and followed the instructions for shorewall found here:

http://www.shorewall.net/Shorewall_Squid_Usage.html#TPROXY

I am using IPv6, so I have adjusted these settings accordingly and redirect via NAT is not an option.

When I try to connect to a remote host such as ipv6.google.com on port 80, the connection gets intercepted by squid fine, which in turn connects to ipv6.google.com, but eventually the connection just times out and I am presented with the squid error page.

If I perform a tcpdump of the connection this is what I get

```
19:09:11.958367 IP6 2001:388:e000:c100:213:e8ff:fe6b:41e5.56667 > 2404:6800:4006:802::1014.80: Flags [S], seq 4011445546, win 12200, options [mss 1220,sackOK,TS val 3255676 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
19:09:12.019139 IP6 2404:6800:4006:802::1014.80 > 2001:388:e000:c100:213:e8ff:fe6b:41e5.56667: Flags [S.], seq 1191029984, ack 4011445547, win 5712, options [mss 1410,sackOK,TS val 967841584 ecr 3255676,nop,wscale 6], length 0
```

Which repeats each time the request TTL times out.

If I use squid as a non-transparent proxy server it is able to handle IPv6 requests without any issues. So for some reason the packets are not finding their way back to squid.

I am running:

```
kernel     - 2.6.39
iptables   - 1.4.11
shorewall6 - 4.4.20
squid3     - 3.1.12
```

**EDIT - I am seeing the same behavior with IPv4**

ip6tables -nL output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
net2fw     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
loc2fw     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
Drop       all      ::/0                 ::/0                
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:INPUT:DROP:"
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
net2loc    all      ::/0                 ::/0                
loc2net    all      ::/0                 ::/0                
lo_fwd     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
Reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:FORWARD:REJECT:"
reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fw2net     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
fw2loc     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
Reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:OUTPUT:REJECT:"
reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 

Chain Drop (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
reject     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:113 /* Auth */
dropBcast  all      ::/0                 ::/0                
dropInvalid  all      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 135,445 /* SMB */
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpts:137:139 /* SMB */
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp spt:137 dpts:1024:65535 /* SMB */
DROP       tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 135,139,445 /* SMB */
dropNotSyn  tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp spt:53 /* Late DNS Replies */

Chain Reject (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
reject     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:113 /* Auth */
dropBcast  all      ::/0                 ::/0                
dropInvalid  all      ::/0                 ::/0                
reject     udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 135,445 /* SMB */
reject     udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpts:137:139 /* SMB */
reject     udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp spt:137 dpts:1024:65535 /* SMB */
reject     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 135,139,445 /* SMB */
dropNotSyn  tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp spt:53 /* Late DNS Replies */

Chain dropBcast (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100::/128 
DROP       all      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80/121 
DROP       all      ::/0                 ff00::/8            

Chain dropInvalid (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID

Chain dropNotSyn (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcpflags:! 0x17/0x02

Chain dynamic (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fw2loc (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain fw2net (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     41       ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain lo_fwd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
sfilter    all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW

Chain lo_in (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW

Chain loc2fw (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain loc2net (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
sfilter    all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain logdrop (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain logflags (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 4 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:logflags:DROP:"
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain logreject (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain net2fw (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
smurfs     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
tcpflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     41       ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:2093
Drop       all      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain net2loc (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
sfilter    all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
smurfs     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
tcpflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100:216:3eff:fe24:dce6/128  multiport dports 25,993
Drop       all      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain reject (9 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100::/128 
DROP       all      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80/121 
DROP       all      ff00::/8             ::/0                
DROP       2        ::/0                 ::/0                
REJECT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
REJECT     icmpv6    ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-addr-unreachable
REJECT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited

Chain sfilter (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:sfilter:DROP:"
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain shorewall (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain smurflog (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:smurfs:DROP:"
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain smurfs (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
smurflog   all      2001:388:e000:c100::/128  ::/0                [goto] 
smurflog   all      2001:388:e000:c100:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80/121  ::/0                [goto] 
smurflog   all      ff00::/8             ::/0                [goto] 

Chain tcpflags (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcpflags: 0x3F/0x29
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcpflags: 0x3F/0x00
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcpflags: 0x06/0x06
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcpflags: 0x03/0x03
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcp spt:0flags: 0x17/0x02
```

ip6tables -t mangle -nL output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
net2fw     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
loc2fw     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
Drop       all      ::/0                 ::/0                
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:INPUT:DROP:"
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
net2loc    all      ::/0                 ::/0                
loc2net    all      ::/0                 ::/0                
lo_fwd     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
Reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:FORWARD:REJECT:"
reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fw2net     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
fw2loc     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
Reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:OUTPUT:REJECT:"
reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 

Chain Drop (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
reject     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:113 /* Auth */
dropBcast  all      ::/0                 ::/0                
dropInvalid  all      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 135,445 /* SMB */
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpts:137:139 /* SMB */
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp spt:137 dpts:1024:65535 /* SMB */
DROP       tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 135,139,445 /* SMB */
dropNotSyn  tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp spt:53 /* Late DNS Replies */

Chain Reject (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
reject     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:113 /* Auth */
dropBcast  all      ::/0                 ::/0                
dropInvalid  all      ::/0                 ::/0                
reject     udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 135,445 /* SMB */
reject     udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpts:137:139 /* SMB */
reject     udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp spt:137 dpts:1024:65535 /* SMB */
reject     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 135,139,445 /* SMB */
dropNotSyn  tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 udp spt:53 /* Late DNS Replies */

Chain dropBcast (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100::/128 
DROP       all      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80/121 
DROP       all      ::/0                 ff00::/8            

Chain dropInvalid (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID

Chain dropNotSyn (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcpflags:! 0x17/0x02

Chain dynamic (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fw2loc (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain fw2net (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     41       ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain lo_fwd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
sfilter    all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW

Chain lo_in (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW

Chain loc2fw (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain loc2net (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
sfilter    all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain logdrop (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain logflags (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 4 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:logflags:DROP:"
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain logreject (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
reject     all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain net2fw (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
smurfs     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
tcpflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     41       ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:2093
Drop       all      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain net2loc (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
sfilter    all      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto] 
dynamic    all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
smurfs     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID,NEW
tcpflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100:216:3eff:fe24:dce6/128  multiport dports 25,993
Drop       all      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain reject (9 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100::/128 
DROP       all      ::/0                 2001:388:e000:c100:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80/121 
DROP       all      ff00::/8             ::/0                
DROP       2        ::/0                 ::/0                
REJECT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
REJECT     icmpv6    ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-addr-unreachable
REJECT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited

Chain sfilter (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:sfilter:DROP:"
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain shorewall (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain smurflog (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      ::/0                 ::/0                 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:smurfs:DROP:"
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                

Chain smurfs (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
smurflog   all      2001:388:e000:c100::/128  ::/0                [goto] 
smurflog   all      2001:388:e000:c100:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80/121  ::/0                [goto] 
smurflog   all      ff00::/8             ::/0                [goto] 

Chain tcpflags (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcpflags: 0x3F/0x29
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcpflags: 0x3F/0x00
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcpflags: 0x06/0x06
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcpflags: 0x03/0x03
logflags   tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                [goto]  tcp spt:0flags: 0x17/0x02
```

Comment: The document you linked to only describes the tcpv4 rules - what does 'iptables -L' show?

Comment: @symcbean - iptables -L will only show the ipv4 rules, I think you mean ip6tables -L, ill add it now

Comment: @symcbean - Added the iptables information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, two rules missing that I assumed that shorewall should have been inserting, running the following resolves the problem.

```
ip6tables -t mangle -N DIVERT
ip6tables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip6tables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t mangle -I tcpre 1 -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
```